# "Store" a remote SSH session?

Tags: ssh, scripting, performance

I am trying to do these in a script. I have to run some commands on a remote host. Currently, I am doing this:

```
ssh root@host 'bash -s' < command1
ssh root@host 'bash -s' < command2
ssh root@host 'bash -s' < command3
```

However, this means that I have to connect to the server repeatedly, which is increasing a lot of time between processing of the commands. I am looking for something like this:

```
varSession=$(ssh root@host 'bash -s')
varSeesion < command1
varSeesion < command2
varSeesion < command3
```

Again, I need to run these commands via a script. I have taken a look at `screen` but I am not sure if it can be used in a script.

Comment: If the sequence is unconditional -- you always do 2 and 3 even if 1 failed -- and no earlier commandfile sets or changes things that cause trouble for a later one, just concatentate the three files `cat command[1-3] >allcommand` and use `ssh u@h bash <allcommand` (note with no positional args _to bash_ `-s` isn't needed)

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/216155/200033

Comment: Above comment is a link to this [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/q/216125) question: "How can I create persistent SSH connection to “stream” commands over a period of time?"

Comment: Why not just copy a script file over, run it, and then delete it? Max of 3 connections then. Reduce it to 2 by modifying the script to delete itself just before it exits...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use a `ControlMaster` and [`ControlPersist`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#ControlPersist) to allow a connection to persist after the command has terminated:

> When used in conjunction with `ControlMaster`, specifies that the
>   master connection should remain open in the background (waiting for
>   future client connections) after the initial client connection has
>   been closed. If set to `no`, then the master connection will not be
>   placed into the background, and will close as soon as the initial
>   client connection is closed. If set to `yes` or `0`, then the master
>   connection will remain in the background indefinitely (until killed or
>   closed via a mechanism such as the “`ssh -O exit`”). If set to a time
>   in seconds, or a time in any of the formats documented in
>   `sshd_config(5)`, then the backgrounded master connection will
>   automatically terminate after it has remained idle (with no client
>   connections) for the specified time.

So, the first SSH command will setup a control file for the connection, and the other two will reuse that connection via that control file. Your `~/.ssh/config` should have something like:

```
Host host
    User root
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPath /tmp/ssh-control-%C
    ControlPersist 30   # or some safe timeout
```

And your script won't need any other changes.

Comment: Problem is that I don't have access to ssh_config file. I am not the administrator.

Comment: It's *your* `~/.ssh_config` file. Not the server's `sshd_config` file.

Comment: @SayantanRoychowdhury besides, you can make `ssh` use another config file with the `-F` option (that will let it _ignore_ the admin's `/etc/ssh_config`). And you can give those `Control...` options on the command line with `-o ControlMaster=auto ...`.

Comment: Well, we have to use ssh from another user. Its aliased to "sudo -i -u someUser". Otherwise it asks for password. And that "someUser" cannot access files from my home. So I can't pass a custom ssh_config file.

Comment: @SayantanRoychowdhury then use mosvy's suggestion, which uses the same options and works the same way. Include things like that in the question, please. We can't read your mind to see if `ssh` in your question is actually something else.

Comment: The default client config is `~/.ssh/config` (not underscore), although as @mosvy says `-F` overrides it and also ignores the systemwide file which is `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (additional directory level)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 oh, yeah, oops.

Comment: While this will work, if all users are using that same `someUser` account to run SSH, then any user on the box can access your master session. Be careful with that.

Answer (score 7):

You could take a hint from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4412238/1595345) on StackOverflow and use a bash *Here document*:

```
ssh root@host 'bash -s' << EOF
  command1
  command2
  command3
EOF
```

Comment: Or `{ echo command1; echo command2; …; } | ssh root@host 'bash -s'` for another approach. +1

Comment: `command1` is the name of a file containing commands, not the command itself.

Comment: From the way the question was worded, it could be either.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `expect` script. It can automate ssh connection and run commands on the remote machine. [This code](https://github.com/rocheparadox/linux_utils/tree/master/ssh_utils) should shed some light on automating the ssh connection.

you are looking for something like this. store the following code in a file `foo.expect`

```
#login to the remote machine
spawn ssh username@hostname
expect "?assword" { send "yourpassword\r"}

#execute the required commands; following demonstration uses echo command
expect "$ " {send "echo The falcon has landed\r"}
expect "$ " {send "echo The falcons have landed\r"}
expect "$ " {send "echo Will the BFR? land? \r"}

#exit from the remote machine
expect "$ " {send "exit\r"}
```

run it as `expect foo.expect`

You need expect application to run this script. It can be installed with the command `apt-get install expect`

[This book](https://www.busindre.com/_media/exploring_expect.pdf) will help you explore expect script. Happy scripting!

Comment: Useful; except I would suggest a passwordless login (e.g. using SSH keys); saving the password *and* pw auth are antipatterns.

Comment: @Piskvor I strongly bias towards passwordless login too but it may not be possible in all the scenarios. Hence I wrote a script that can feed the password when required. :)

Answer (score 3):

## Independant *file descriptor* for one or more *SSH* connections

I addition to *`ControlPath`* and *`ControlPersist`* correct way, proposed by [muru's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/552724/27653), I would like to present an alternative:

### Method

1. Create a fifo you will use for ssh's outputs

   You have to create this file in a path you are confident

   ```
   mkfifo $HOME/sshfifo
   ```
2. Run *long-running* command:

   ```
   exec 8> >(exec ssh user@host /bin/bash >$HOME/sshfifo
   exec 9<$HOME/sshfifo
   ```
3. Then now you don't need anymore the fifo

   ```
   rm $HOME/sshfifo
   ```
4. You are now ready to send and recieve commands from your connection:

   ```
   echo >&8 uptime
   while read -t .002 -r -u 9 answer;do echo "$answer";done
   ```

   Nota: `0.002 seconds` may be insufficient on poor internet connections... Timeout could be useless depending on type of requests. At all this could be adapted to which kind of dialog is attented.

   And so on...

   ```
   myremote() {
       echo "$@" >&8
       while IFS= read -t .02 -r -u 9 answer;do
            echo "$answer"
       done
   }
   ```
5. This will stay until you explicitely close this connection:

   ```
   exec 8>&-
   exec 9<&-
   ```

### Further

This is not perfect. You could

- Bind *STDERR* too, with a second fifo

  ```
  mkfifo $HOME/sshfifo{out,err}
  exec 8> >(exec ssh user@host /bin/bash >$HOME/sshfifoout 2>$HOME/sshfifoerr)
  exec 9<$HOME/sshfifoout
  exec 10<$HOME/sshfifoerr
  rm $HOME/sshfifo{out,err}
  ```
- Use interactive bash, then reduce timeout

  ```
  mkfifo $HOME/sshfifo{out,err}
  exec 8> >(exec ssh -tT user@host /bin/bash -i >$HOME/sshfifoout 2>$HOME/sshfifoerr)
  exec 9<$HOME/sshfifoout
  exec 10<$HOME/sshfifoerr
  rm $HOME/sshfifo{out,err}
  echo >&8 'set -i;PS1="ReAdY aS BoUnD\\n"'
  while IFS= read -d '' -rn 1 -t .02 -u 9 foo;do echo -n "$foo";done
  while IFS= read -d '' -rn 1 -t .02 -u 10 foo;do echo -n "$foo";done
  ```

  ... then watching for `/^ReAdY aS BoUnD$/` from `fd/10` as marker for *end of execution of last command*, you could avoid timout for STDERR (`-u 10`), then reduce *timemout* for STDOUT (`-u 9 -t .002`).

### And from there

It is even possible to *open* multiple connection to be used together

```
mkfifo $HOME/sshfifo
exec 8> >(exec ssh user1@hostA /bin/bash >$HOME/sshfifo 2>&1)
exec 9<$HOME/sshfifo
rm $HOME/sshfifo

mkfifo $HOME/sshfifo
exec 11> >(exec ssh user2@hostB /bin/bash >$HOME/sshfifo 2>&1)
exec 12<$HOME/sshfifo
rm $HOME/sshfifo
```

Then

```
tee <<<uptime /dev/fd/8 >&11
read -u  9 -t .02 ansA
read -u 12 -t .02 ansB
```

to send same command *simultaneously* to both ends...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cat` to concatenate all the files and then pipe them to `ssh`.

```
cat command1 command2 command3 | ssh root@host 'bash -s'
```